# Python tkinter creating two windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently trying to create two windows with a tkinter program but it doesn't seem to be working. It was only recently that i just moved over my game to tkinter and it is the first time working with tkinter. Due to that I have no clue why this isn't working.

This is my first window and its working fine

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            super().__init__(master)
            self.pack()
            self.create_widgets()
            self.crafting_listbox
```

My second window though isn't working

```
class Application_2(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            super().__init__(master)
            self.pack()
            self.crafting_listbox()
```

Then the finishing bit

```
 root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

I am unsure why this isn't working, whats going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never call your second Frame.

To make a second window use the `Toplevel` class.

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)

second_win = tk.Toplevel(root)
app2 = Application_2(second_win)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks that helped!